# How to load related data (e.g. Includes) for EFCore's TemporalAll?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, temporal

The following code joins multiple tables with the TemporalAll function (e.g. FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL) which are JOINED using a typical Id/FK join and "BETWEEN" condition to ensure all of the data is at a particular point in time. That works lovely. The problem is the inability to load related data such as "Patron" below using the EFCore "Include" feature. How should this be accomplished?

I found a similiar question (issue) which seems to indicate that this feature is not supported: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26704

```
        var query =
            from rr in coreService.UnitOfWork.Repository<RewardsRedemption>().TemporalAll()!
            from rcr in coreService.UnitOfWork.Repository<RewardsCatalogReward>().TemporalAll()!
                .Where(rcr => rcr.Id == rr.Id)
                .Where(rcr => EF.Property<DateTime>(rr, "ValidFrom") >= EF.Property<DateTime>(rcr, "ValidFrom") &&
                                              EF.Property<DateTime>(rr, "ValidFrom") <= EF.Property<DateTime>(rcr, "ValidTo"))
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            from p in coreService.UnitOfWork.Repository<Patron>().TemporalAll()!
                .Where(p => p.Id == rr.PatronId)
                .Where(p => EF.Property<DateTime>(rr, "ValidFrom") >= EF.Property<DateTime>(p, "ValidFrom") &&
                                  EF.Property<DateTime>(rr, "ValidFrom") <= EF.Property<DateTime>(p, "ValidTo"))
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            where
                rr.Id == 1
            select rr;
        var data = await coreService.UnitOfWork.Repository<RewardsRedemption>().ListAsync(query, coreService.GetIncludesForDataRetrieve<RewardsRedemption>(defaultIncludesForDataRetrieve));
        return coreService.AutoMapper.Map<IList<RewardsRedemption>, IReadOnlyCollection<FullRewardsRedemptionDTO>>(data!);
```